# How to cast a string to nvarchar?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have a text box and I want to save the output result to **Unicode**  (`nvarchar` in SQL Server), for the save operation I used Entity Framework, my code works fine, my problem is just to convert the text box result to Unicode, because when i saved the result it saved as "?" in Sql Server.
NB:**i use Arabic letters.**, this is my code , and column definition:
**Code** :

```
//Button add new car into database
    private void BtnAddNewCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        v.brand = TxBoxBrand.Text;
        v.car_number = TxBoxCarNumber.Text;//Text Box that i want to convert to Unicode (Arabic letters)
        v.color = CmBoxColorPicker.Text;
        v.model = TxBoxModel.Text;
        v.picture = ImageToByteArray(filename);
        v.cin_driver= CmBoxCarOwner.Text;
        context.Vehicles.Add(v);
        context.SaveChanges();
        NotifyWelcome.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "The vehicle " + TxBoxBrand.Text + " was successfully added", " Have a ice drive", ToolTipIcon.Info);
        CarClear();
        VLoad.Enabled = true;
        CmVLoad.Enabled = false;
        MyMessageBox.ShowBox("The vehicle " + TxBoxBrand.Text + " as successfully added", "Notify");
    }
```

**Column definition** :

```
// TxBoxCarNumber
        // 
        this.TxBoxCarNumber.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Ubuntu", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.TxBoxCarNumber.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(272, 30);
        this.TxBoxCarNumber.Name = "TxBoxCarNumber";
        this.TxBoxCarNumber.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(142, 21);
        this.TxBoxCarNumber.TabIndex = 0;
        this.TxBoxCarNumber.TabStop = false;
```

Comment: _i update my question_  - not with the info I asked for.

Comment: It done, i update the code

Comment: Yes, it's getting better. But `TxBoxCarNumber` is not the coulmn I meant, the problem is in `v.car_number`. You should be able to verify with a debugger. So what is `v`?  Entity framework?

Comment: Still not with the information. The WinForms-generated code ise useless and irrelevant here, Henk wanted the column definition from the database. It's very likely that the column is just a `varchar` one and thus text gets mangled.

Comment: Ok the column type is nvarchar(50), yes the v is entity framework